# How to make dynamic variable with a lopping flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

i have a code in flutter like this :

```
    for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++){
       int examp+i = 0;
     }
```

and I want output like this:

- int examp0 = 0;
- int examp1 = 0;
- int examp2 = 0;
- ......

can u help me?

Comment: This is not possible. Create a list.

Comment: do you want do simply print this output?

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not possible. Check out [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57757657/15469537), which suggests using a map

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
List exampleList = [];

for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++){
    exampleList[0] = 0;
}
```

Where `exampleList[0] = example0, exampleList[1] = example1`